# HTML 5 canvas globalCompositeOperation (eraser) issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Ok, I built a drawing system a few months back which basically lets the user draw on the canvas. Some features that I included were drawing with a user defined color and size of the stroke, eraser, and undo/redo.

I was just going over some projects to see how they were functioning still and noticed a new issue that wasn't happening when I built and published this sketch tool.

My issue is, after the user has drawn whatever and then goes to the eraser to erase a portion of the sketch, the entire canvas is cleared on mousedown. This did not happen before. The eraser is supposed to follow the cursor and clear the stroke path that the mouse takes. So I'm wondering if there were any changes to how the canvas reads the global composite operation or something. I've searched stack and google and can't find any clear answers so I'm hoping maybe someone else has ran into this issue.

I also noticed that when I switch back to the pen tool after the eraser clears the canvas nothing gets drawn anymore. Even if I undo, it will show the previous stroke that was erased but the draw tool no longer does anything.

If I try to erase everything is cleared, but if I undo it will bring back what was stored before the eraser was attempted.

Here are the scripts that I used for drawing and erasing. Any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I would also like to note that this issue is happening in the latest version of chrome, firefox, and IE 11.

EDIT: I forgot to mention. After discovering this issue, I tried to switch the globalCompositeOperation to "destination-out" but it did not leave a solid stroke like I would like. It was only making a series of dots (which were erasing) but it wasn't smooth/clean like it should be.

EDIT: Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/p889d/

```
function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
if (isDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
    ctx.strokeStyle = gd.color;             
    ctx.lineWidth = gd.toolSize;            
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}

function Erase(x, y, isDown) {
if (isDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="copy";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";              
    ctx.lineWidth = gd.toolSize;            
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.closePath();    
    ctx.stroke();   
}
   lastX = x;
   lastY = y;
}

$canvas.bind("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {                         
    mousePressed = true;    

    lastX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    lastY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

    if (gd.pushIt == true) {    
        if (gd.tool == 'marker') {
            Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
        } 
        if (gd.tool == 'eraser') {
            Erase(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
        }
    }
    if (gd.pushIt == false) {
        invisibleCanvas(e, $(this));
    }
    if ($(".multi-item-menu").is(":visible")) {
        $(".multi-item-menu").fadeOut(400);
    }
    if ($("#draw-colors-pallet").is(":visible")) {
        $("#draw-colors-pallet").fadeOut(400);
    }

    // for text area tool
    if (gd.tool == 'text') {        
        mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX !== 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
        mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY !== 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;

        start_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        start_mouse.y = mouse.y;
    }
});

$canvas.bind("mousemove touchmove", function (e) {                          
    if (mousePressed == true && gd.pushIt == true) {
        if (gd.tool == 'marker') {
            Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
        } 
        if (gd.tool == 'eraser') {
            Erase(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
        }

        if (gd.tool == 'text') {
            mouse.x = typeof e.offsetX !== 'undefined' ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
            mouse.y = typeof e.offsetY !== 'undefined' ? e.offsetY : e.layerY;

            adjustTextArea();
        }
    }
    if (gd.pushIt == false) {
        var x = e.pageX,
            y = e.pageY;

        mousePressed = false;

        if (x !== lastX || y !== lastY) {
            invisibleCanvas(e, $(this));
        }

        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    } 
});
```

Comment: your strokeStyle has a null opacity, so there are little chances for anything to draw.

Comment: @GameAlchemist How is it null? I thought rgba(0,0,0,0) was the correct way to define it? Any input on what I should try changing it to?

Comment: the last component of a rgba() color is the alpha, in 0.0-1.0 range. If 0, nothing will draw (unless you use a specific blending mode, but you're using composite modes, not blending modes here). Fix is easy : use rgb(,,) or rgba(,,,1).

Comment: @GameAlchemist I tried your suggestion and am still facing the same issue :(. tried rgba(0,0,0) and rgba(0,0,0,0.0) the only difference now is the cursor shows a black dot but still clears the entire canvas

Comment: I just noticed that when I switch back to the pen tool after the eraser clears the canvas nothing gets drawn anymore.

Comment: If you could setup a fiddle that would be just great to understand / debug your issue.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I have added the link to the fiddle in the OP. Thank you for taking the time to look at this with me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: What browser are you using? I modified your demo to use destination-out and it appears to be working perfectly in Firefox 30.0.

Comment: @scribblemaniac I tested in ff 30, ie 11, and chrome 38

Comment: @scribblemaniac When you use destination out, is the erase stroke solid or spotty? When I did it, it was erasing but it was not a solid stroke

Comment: @xxstevenxo It is a single continuous stroke for me, try out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scribblemaniac/85K7W/) and let me know if it is spotty for you.

Comment: @scribblemaniac Thank you so much! Post your solution and I'll mark it solved. Thank you.

Comment: @scribblemaniac The eraser works great, thank you! I just noticed that after i use the eraser using the undo feature will clear the entire canvas, for some reason it's not pushing the image to the memory array. This happens in the fiddle you shared as well. Any idea why destination-out would effect the img storage?

Comment: @scribblemaniac It only happens directly after you erase if you click undo. If I erase and then use the pen tool again it all works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: @xxstevenxo I have just updated my answer to address this problem as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your eraser working again, you want to change these lines in your Erase function:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="copy";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
```

to these:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
```

As you can see in [this article](http://www.rekim.com/2011/02/11/html5-canvas-globalcompositeoperation-browser-handling/), there was a time when Firefox, Chrome, and Webkit did not support the value `copy`. I would guess that when your program broke when the browsers implemented this feature.

EDIT:
For some reason toDataUrl doesn't seem to properly reflect the changes with the eraser. If you change the values stored in your cPushArray to image data from ctx.getImageData and put the data back on the canvas with ctx.putImageData, it works just fine.

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/scribblemaniac/85K7W/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Using getImageData will still work on older version of these browsers right?

Comment: @xxstevenxo Yes, any browser that supports the canvas element should support getImageData.